# Why is my program "Teen talk" not working?

Tags: java

I'm a highschooler who is taking computer science this year, and I can't figure out why my program "teen talk" isn't working. I am writing a simple method, where when a string parameter is put in, it adds "like" after every space to make it sound like a teenager. But when I try to run the program, it just sits there and loads.

This is my code:

```
public class Scratchpad extends ConsoleProgram
{
public void run()
{
    //Tests
    teenTalk("This is so cool");
}

public String teenTalk(String sentence)
{
    //Code here
    String result = "";
    
    //Goes through each character in the string, looking for a
    //space to add "like" after and adds it to the string result.
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
    {
        while(sentence.charAt(i) != ' ')
        {
            result += sentence.charAt(i);
        }
        result += "like ";
    }
    return result;
    }
}
```

Note: I am not using a regular java ouputer, I am using a website called CodeHS. So perhaps it may be a little different than normal java code.

I am trying to run the program and it just sits there and loads.

Comment: change public void run() to public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: Where is your main program and from what library is `ConsoleProgram` that your class extens?

Comment: Forget about the loops. Just do this: `sentence = sentence.replace(" ", " like ");`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
{
    while(sentence.charAt(i) != ' ') // This code will loop forever
    {
        result += sentence.charAt(i);
    }
    result += "like ";
}
```

The while statement above will loop forever because the first character it hits will be a 'T' which is not a space. This while statement never increments `i` so it never moves from checking if the 'T' is a space.

Instead of using while, try using a simple if

```
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
{
    if(sentence.charAt(i) != ' ')
    {
        result += sentence.charAt(i);
    }
    result += "like ";
}
```